# How can I combine these 2 formulas into one in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to combine this formula in Excell `=IF(C73>0, (C73+20),"")` with another formula `=IF(C73>0, (C73+55),"")`

But the second formula will only apply if the A73 Cell is equal to the value "RSV"

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `IF`.

In your example the two formulas seem to differ in one number (55 vs. 20) only, so it is easier to substitute the number with an inner `IF(...)`.

```
=IF(C73>0, C73+IF(A73="RSV", 55, 20), "")
```

If the formulas would differ in more parts, it would be better to wrap both in an outer `IF`

```
=IF(A73="RSV", IF(C73>0, (C73+55),""), IF(C73>0, (C73+20),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest IF functions together, see breakdown below

```
=IF(logic, Value if logic is true, value if logic is false")

=IF(A73="RSV", second formula here, first formula here")

=IF(A73="RSV", IF(C73>0, (C73+55),""), IF(C73>0, (C73+20),""))
```